# Unable to click into input element when rendered inside of CheckboxCard component

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm using Chakra UI and am having trouble getting an text Input element to work when rendered inside of another component. The text Input element cannot be clicked into or focused when it is rendered inside the CheckboxCard component. Rendering other components inside CheckboxCard, such as a Button, works as expected.

This is the only instance in which I have encountered this problem. I cannot find anything obvious reasons in the source code for the CheckboxCard component and am hoping that someone else can.

Here is an example of the problem in Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-snow-wix7hx?file=/src/App.js

The CheckboxCard source code looks like this:

```
export const CheckboxCard = (props: RadioCardProps) => {

  const { checkboxProps, children, outsideCheckboxClickContent, ...rest } =
    props;

  const { getInputProps, getCheckboxProps, getLabelProps, state } =
    useCheckbox(checkboxProps);

  return (
    <Box
      as="label"
      cursor="pointer"
      {...getLabelProps()}
      sx={{
        ".focus-visible + [data-focus]": {
          boxShadow: "outline",
          zIndex: 1,
        },
      }}
    >
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      <Box {...getCheckboxProps()} {...rest}>
        <Stack direction="row">
          <Box>{children}</Box>
          <Checkbox
            pointerEvents="none"
            isFocusable={false}
            isChecked={state.isChecked}
          />
        </Stack>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

The code for the input element rendered inside the Checkbox card looks like this:

```
<CheckboxCard>
  <Input/>
</CheckboxCard>
```